# Is component based fetching a bad idea for list views?

Tags: reactjs, performance, request, frontend, components

For an application I am working on, we've recently made some changes to how we fetch data which gives us a lot more flexibility.

Due to this change a new possibility opened up for up: Very granular data fetching.

Overall we will definitely go towards a direction that when you are on a page with may components, they all can subscribe to their own data they want.

But we could go even further with this. We could start implementing this into list views.

It would definitely work, I am just not sure what is the best practice here. The trade of basically is this:

Way less data over-fetching because we can granularily decide which data is needed and don't need to pro-actively fetch data for a whole section of the application.
On the downside: Much more requests. Because we are now deciding on a component level whether to fetch data or not, it has the trade-off that each component could possibly trigger his own request.

For a general section the up-side of less data over-fetching is obvious in our application that it is worth it.
But I am not sure what to think for list views.

[image]

First of all there is the question of UX, whether this looks a bit too funky. But for this question I want to **focus on the technical aspect**. Because I feel like it is a bad idea to trigger THAT many fetches. Since in a list (in our application the limit would be like 100 items in a list), every item will trigger a request. So for a list with 100 items, and let's say two columns, it could potentiall trigger up to 201 fetches.

What are commonly accepted best practices for this? Are there more specific downsights I am not seeing, or does it just in general not make sense performance whise or smth?

Thank you in advance!

(note, no real people are in that list, these are random names :))